# How to update array value then store/save it in the array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am operating with array that looks like this:

```
$pms = array(
    'msg1' => array(
        'status' => 'unread',
        'subject' => 'bla bla'
    ),
    'msg2' => array(
        'status' => 'unread',
        'subject' => 'test..'
    ),
    'msg3' => array(
        'status' => 'unread',
        'subject' => 'moreee..'
    )
);
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to select 'msg3' for example, update the status from 'unread' to 'read' and put it back in its position in the array.

How to do that?

Comment: `$pms['msg3']['status'] = 'read';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign the new value to it like any other array variable:

```
$pms['msg3']['status'] = 'read';
```

Comment: Pretty impressive how fast you were able to extract what he wanted